# C# Concatenating two DataTable columns (typeof string) one of which may be null

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have this code:

```
dt.Columns.Add("denumire", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("serie", typeof (string));
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("serie_denumire");
dc.Expression = string.Format("{0}+' '+{1}", "denumire", "serie");
dt.Columns.Add(dc);
```

The column "serie" can have null values (from the DB) but "denumire" always has a value. They're both strings and when I try to concatenate them and a row in "serie" is null the end result ("denumire" + "serie") is null.

Same with:

```
 dt.Columns.Add("denumire", typeof(string));  
 dt.Columns.Add("serie", typeof (string));  
 dt.Columns.Add("serie_denumire", typeof (string), "denumire + ' ' + serie");
```

I should mention that the end result is displayed in a combobox:

```
 combobox1.DisplayMember = "serie_denumire";
```

PS: sorry for the formatting (4 spaces for code does not seem to work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IsNull()` in your expression:

`dc.Expression = string.Format("{0}+' '+IsNull({1}, '')", "denumire", "serie");`

Comment: This works! Thanks! But the item in the combobox in which "serie" is not null displays the text selected and invisible (only blue color but if I copy and paste somewhere else the text is there).

Comment: @user2945793 That sounds like a separate issue.

Comment: It sounds like it but it happened right after I implemented the change you suggested.